# Is it a good practice to use global references in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For example the javascript code is:

```
function a() {  
    this.Foo = function() {//...}
}
```

What I usually do is that I create a global reference:

```
_a = new a();
```

Then use it wherever I want in body or other script area:

```
_a.Foo()
```

Is this good or bad practice? or is there a better/more professional way to do that?

Comment: Your `_a.Foo()` doesn't do (exactly) what you think it does ;-) either do `a.prototype.Foo = function() { }` or inside the constructor: `this.Foo = function() { }`

Comment: Oh that's a typo. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general Javascript developers try to avoid this, because of the possibility of different libraries conflicting with each other in the global scope.  To avoid this, consider (if possible) using what's called a *closure* to create a private scope for your variable.  That looks like this:

```
(function() {
    _a = new a();
})();
```

Everything declared inside the inner function is invisible to code outside it.

If you can't use a closure for whatever reason, then an alternative would be to create a "namespace" for your variables.

```
var MyCompany = { };
MyCompany.MyLibrary = { };
MyCompany.MyLibrary._a = new a();
```

This way you are able to restrict your code to acquiring a single global name (MyCompany), with other variables and methods residing inside that namespace.

Comment: Well after some research I found another namespace declaration like this: var MyCompany = MyCompany || {};   What's the difference? Also what MyCompany here actually is? A function? object? or whatever?

Comment: @NSF If I recall properly, that is a way of checking if an object is null (which JavaScript will normally treat as roughly equivalent to 'false'), and if so, a new JavaScript object is created.

Comment: @NSF Tieson T. is exactly right, that statement basically says "get the existing reference, or create it if it doesn't exist".  And yes, it's an object.

Comment: The primary reason for avoiding global variables is the chance of "collision" with same–named properties from aonther source. Useing a "namesapce" object doesn't afford any reduction in risk in that regard, you are just as likely to collide with `mylibrary.somemethod` as `mylibrary_somemethod`. Using an object has other benefits though, but they are minor and mostly related to style. The best protection is to use a prefix that is currently unused by any library and is unlikely to be chosen. Many libraries have claimed "$" (highlighting why it was a bad choice in the first place).

Comment: @RobG good points, but if you have multiple variable declarations _a, _b, _c, etc, wouldn't having a single namespace at least reduce the "surface area" so to speak?

Comment: @dbaseman—it's a simple matter of chance. A "namespace" just adds more characters to the identifier, it doesn't make the chance of collision any less likely if you replace the "." in the identifier with a "_". I chose xLib some time ago, then discovered xLibrary. Too close for comfort.